# how to send messages using socket.io

Tags: javascript, apache, sockets, node.js

I want to use socket.io and node as a layer for my "push notification feature", so I'm running both apache and node.

I have the following code on my server (node)

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
    , io = require('C:/path/to/file/socket.io').listen(app)
    , fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8080);

function handler(req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    fs.readFile('C:/path/to/file/index.html',
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.writeHead(500);
                return res.end('Error loading index.html');
            }

            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
        });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('my event', function (msg) {
        console.log("DATA!!!");
    });
});
```

the page is then served by apache from localhost without 8080 port

and on the client I have the following code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

and when a button is clicked:

```
socket.emit('my event', {data:"some data"});
```

I see nothing on the node console ... why is that? cross domain issue?

**Update:**
it works just fine on safari 5.1.5 and even IE 9, but not on chrome(18.0.1025.151) or firefox (11.0) ... what am I missing?

here is the node log:

```
   info  - socket.io started
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized 4944162402088095824
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/4944162402088095824
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client 4944162402088095824
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/4944162402088095824?t=13
33977095905
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 4944162402088095824
```

Answer (score 3):

That should work fine, just make sure that in your index.html you have :

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

also, since you're serving your page via Apache, you really don't need the handler and the http server in you node file.
this should work just fine :

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('my event', function (msg) {
        console.log("DATA!!!");
    });
});
```

and for the index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
                $("#button").click(function() {
                    socket.emit('my event' ,"Hello World!");
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" id='button'>Send Message</button> 
    </body>

</html>
```

**Edit:** This works in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Obviously my issue is local, your example works fine on safari and IE but not on my chrome or firefox ... where should I look? 
P.S: I'm messing around with WebRTC so this feature is enabled on my chrome ("Enable MediaStream. Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS
Enable MediaStream, GetUserMedia, and PeerConnection APIs for WebRTC functionality. More info at webrtc.org."), tried disabling it with no success ... any other idea?

Comment: tried re-installing chrome ... no go :(
more info: I'm running node on windows 7, and I use full path to socket.io like so "C:\Users\shlomis\node_modules\socket.io" (couldn't figure it out) ... could that be related?

Comment: This is odd... try to open Chrome developper tools, or Firebug on Firefox, and open the 'net' tab, it could give you more informations about what's happening under the hood

Comment: it seems that FF and chrome fallback to log polling after a few seconds ... I have no clue why

Comment: update: I've added 
socket.on('connect', function () {
                console.log("connected");
            });
and it never fires on chrome